# State glitch in react-electron application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, vite

I have a Recorder.jsx file as follows:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { channels } from '../../../../shared'
import { Button } from 'primereact/button'

const { ipcRenderer } = electron

function Recorder() {
  const [sources, setSources] = useState([])

  const handleSources = (_, sources) => {
    setSources(sources)
  }

  const getScreenSources = () => {
    ipcRenderer.send(channels.GET_SOURCES)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on(channels.GET_SOURCES, handleSources)
    // Clean the listener after the component is dismounted
    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners()
    }
  }, [])

  const Test = () => {
    ipcRenderer.send(channels.TEST)
  }

  const Test1 = () => {
    console.log('Test ', sources)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on(channels.TEST, Test1)

    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Button label="Test" onClick={Test} />
      <Button label="Get Sources" onClick={getScreenSources} />
      {sources &&
        sources.map((source) => {
          return <li>{source.name}</li>
        })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Recorder
```

And I have this in my electron app's main/index.js file:

```
...
ipcMain.on(channels.GET_SOURCES, async (e) => {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen']
  })

  e.sender.send(channels.GET_SOURCES, inputSources)
})

ipcMain.on(channels.TEST, async (e) => {
  // createRecordActionsWindow()
  e.sender.send(channels.TEST)
})
...
```

I clicked on "Get Sources" button and fetched all the sources, they are available in 'sources' state and are displayed as list items.

Now when I click on "Test" button and Test1 function runs, but the console log shows empty sources array instead of filled array.

I expected sources array to be filled here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made two common mistakes. First is the empty dependency array on your second `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ipcRenderer.on(channels.TEST, Test1)

  return () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners()
  }
}, [])
```

An empty dependency array means that the effect will never re-run, and thus if you use a state in it, it will keep its initial value. Since your effect depends on `Test1`, and that `Test1` depends on `sources`, you should use a [`useCallback`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) and [make your dependencies match the code](https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#dependencies-should-match-the-code):

```js
const Test1 = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('Test ', sources);
}, [sources]);

useEffect(() => {
  ipcRenderer.on(channels.TEST, Test1);

  return () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners();
  }
}, [Test1]);
```

Also be careful with these [`removeAllListeners()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovealllistenerschannel), what you actually want is to remove *only* whatever listener is used in the effect, and not *all* listeners. For this you should pass the channel's name to `removeAllListeners()`, or use [`removeListener()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener) instead.

---

The second mistake is that you probably don't want to use [`send`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)/[`on`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener)/[`on`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener), if you want to call main and get a response, you can simply use [`invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)/[`handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener). For example:

**Renderer**

```js
const getScreenSources = async () => {
  const source = await ipcRenderer.invoke(channels.GET_SOURCES);
  setSources(sources);
};
```

**Main**

```js
ipcMain.handle(channels.GET_SOURCES, () => (
  desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen']
  })
));
```

It also means that the `useEffect`s are no longer necessary.